# what does this "interest" in this sentence exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

what does this sentence exactly mean?

> It's in the company's interest for you to do the course.

Comment: [Interest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interest), definition 3: advantage, benefit

Comment: This is often expressed as "best interest" – _It's in the company's best interest for you to do the course._ The word "best" isn't needed, but you'll [see it often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+*+best+interest&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: It means that it would be good for the company if you did the course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an **interest in** ***something*** it means you have strong link either economically or emotionally to it.

The company's **interest**, in general, is to make money and be profitable. Many companies believe that if their workers are better educated, more knowledgeable about their services, and motivated it will help the company.

Your **interest** in the company is to help the company be profitable (so you get paid) and to help the company grow (for career advancement and especially if you have profit sharing)

So, it is in the company's **interest** that you take the course, become better at what you do and in the long run it will ultimately help the company, and in turn should also benefit you.